# stylecop / resharper configuration to not add comments

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop

how to configure stylecop or resharper to NOT add meaningless comments when doing "cleanup code"??

OK (KEEP/NICE TO HAVE):

have region tags:

```
#region Public Properties
```

REMOVE:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description.
    /// </summary>
```

OR

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The _context.
    /// </summary>
    private static HttpContextBase _context;
```

Comment: Those aren't "meaningless comments" - you're meant to fill them in with information about your objects.  Information in the summary tags is what is seen by consumers of your objects in intellisense, etc.

Comment: understood. but i still need to remove it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Reshaper->Options->Tools->Code Cleanup, modify or create a new cleanup profile and de-select all the Stylecop->Documentation items:

[image]